# Find the minimum value of $\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+2bxy+9y^{2})-y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the minimum value of $f=\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+2bxy+9y^{2})-y$

I know that there's a theorem which states $P(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{T}Ax-x^{T}b$ reaches min at the point $Ax=b$ at $P_{min}=-\frac{1}{2}b^{T}A^{-1}b$.

I first tried to write the function $f$ in the form of $P(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{T}Ax-x^{T}b$, so

$\frac{1}{2}(\begin{bmatrix}x &y \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&2b\\2b&9\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix})
-\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

And $P_{min}=-\frac{1}{2}b^{T}A^{-1}b$

$=-\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{9-4b^{2}}\begin{bmatrix}9&-2b\\-2b&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$=-\frac{1}{2(9-4b^{2})}$

However the answer key says that the min is $-\frac{1}{2(9-b^{2})}$, where did I go wrong?

Comment: If you just solve $\partial f/\partial x = 0$, $\partial f/\partial y = 0$, you get a local min of $-(2(9-b^2))^{-1}$ quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your matrix A is not right. It should be:

1    b

b    9.

In other words, a(11) = 1, a(12) = b = a(21), and a(22) = 9.

Comment: and, if $|b| \geq 3,$ there is no minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to solve $\nabla f = 0$, in other words:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x + by = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = bx + 9y - 1 = 0$$

This is a linear system of two variables in two equations and hence is readily solved to get your minimizing point (if it exists).